# Fabric.js: Resize canvas and continue working

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am working with Fabric.js manipulation images uploaded by users.

Here is how the application works

[image]

The uploaded image can be moved and worked on on the entire canvas (grey area). Once finished, I only need the middle area.

One the user clicks `save`, currently I save the green area as an image, but I also need to resize the whole canvas to be only the green area.

I tried changing the `width` and `height` of the whole canvas and then `redrawAll()`, but the canvas goes bottom left and only a small portion of the working area is visible, the rest is empty gray.

Is it possible to take a snapshot of the green area and continuing working on the canvas ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to scale your objects on a canvas? For example, green area is twice smaller than grey area, which means you have to scale all your objects on a canvas by 0.5.

Comment: Scaling does not work in this situation. I need everything in the green area to remain exactly how they are, I just need a way to 'cover' outside that area. I tried adding two overlays, one that covers the working area(with the highest ID/z-index) and one the covers the whole canvas(with ID/z-index - 1 relative to the other overlay) but it does not work either.

Comment: What kind of manipulation are you trying to do on a working area? Is it some kind of drawing?

Comment: @Observer It is a composition of multiple images one on top of another. It's the design for a product and the final product it's the size of the green area. That is why I need to save the object in that area as they are. I also tried with clipping but with no luck

Comment: Clipping should work in that case. Can you include your logic with clipping? What was the issue with clipping?

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late, in the end I managed to do it with clipping, basically hiding the area around the green zone. Thank you

Comment: Please even if you solved, check the answer i added. that shows you how you should work on those situations with fabricjs

Answer (score 4):

You should do extensive use of viewportTransform.

let's make an example:
you have a canvas element of 1000x1000 and you want to work on an area of 500x500 pixels.

You set the green area using a green image or a green rect of 500x500 as background image, with top left 0,0. Then you set the viewportTransform of the fabric canvas to [1, 0, 0, 1, 250, 250] this will make your canvas translate to right bottom of that grey border.

When is time to save, you have 2 choices:

1) set a viewportTransform that lets you cover everything of the original canvas and export to dataurl

2) you create an offscreen canvas of 500x500px, you move the objects over there, without touching the new canvas zoom and pan ( viewport transform ) and export that canvas to dataUrl

The snippet has some number for examples, but you need to fully understand how to use and check also the toDataUrl options of fabricCanvas.

```js
var butt = document.getElementById('butt');
butt.onclick = function() {
canvas.viewportTransform = [2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0];
var img = document.getElementById('export');
img.src = canvas.toDataURL()
canvas.viewportTransform = [1, 0, 0, 1, 250, 250];
canvas.renderAll();
}

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { backgroundColor: 'grey' });

var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 500, height: 500, fill: 'green'})
canvas.backgroundImage = rect;
canvas.viewportTransform = [1, 0, 0, 1, 250, 250];
var exampleRect = new fabric.Rect({left: 5, top: 5, width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'red' });
canvas.add(exampleRect);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<img id="export" />
<button id="butt" >export</button>
<canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```